# How can I get the array length in nlohmann's json library?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am using nlohmann/json lib and want to get the length of a json array. Image i have:

```
[
"test",
"test2"
]
```

and want to recieve the length (2). When i tried the .length() method, it showed me this error:

> using json = using json = class nlohmann::basic_json<>' {aka 'class nlohmann::basic_json<>'} has no member named 'length

so how can I get the length in this library?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use `myJsonArray.size()` method here.